# Which selector do I need to select an option by its text?

Tags: jquery

I need to check if a `<select>` has an option whose text is equal to a specific value.

For example, if there's an `<option value="123">abc</option>`, I would be looking for "abc".

Is there a selector to do this?

Im looking for something similar to `$('#select option[value="123"]');` but for the text.

Comment: Hmm... the `has` in SLaks answer is useful, but the point in Floyds answer is also good... I dont know what to accept.

Comment: also, are these case sensitive? (im looking for case-insensitivity and can always just convert to lower

Comment: I use the JavaScript core function .toLowerCase() and compare, if case-insensitivity is required. Also, accept as answer the one that is most useful for your asked question. :)

Comment: it don't work for a dropdown having multiselect API?? I tried all possible solutions bt no luck. I'm using eric hynd's multiselect dropdowm API. Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 360, accepted):

This could help:

```
$('#test').find('option[text="B"]').val();
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmvf6/1/)

This would give you the option with text `B` and not the ones which has text that contains `B`.

*For recent versions of jQuery the above does not work.* As commented by [Quandary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155077/quandary) below, this is what works for jQuery 1.9.1:

```
$('#test option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "B"; }).val();
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/nmvf6/2019/)

Comment: this does not work with the latest versions of jquery (if you remove 'value=' from <option>)

Comment: @KevinDeus: Why the downvote!? The answer was for the version of jQuery then!

Comment: @Floyd Pink: Because it doesn't work anymore and hasn't been updated.

Comment: Instead, use $('#test option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "B"; }).val();

Comment: @Quandary Still, it's not a valid reason to vote the answer down when a short comment would suffice. Or do you expect of him to retest all his answers for every new release of jQuery?

Comment: @WynandB LOL I like your question about testing all his answers, good stuff, and good point!

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui: I just tested it with jQuery 1.9.1 and it is working for me. Can you tell me why you think it does not work?

Comment: I think the downvote is due to the fact that the above example just findes the selected value, and does not set the selected value.

Comment: nivs1987 is right, 
morehover I think you must use "text" instead of "html", something like
val selVal= $('#test option').filter(function () { return $(this).text() == "B"; }).val();
then you must use selVal to select the wanted option with
$('#test').val(selVal);

Comment: I found .text() is better than .html() since I needed to find options with an &. .html() read the option as &amp; not &.

Comment: I tried both options but none worked in jQuery v3.5.1

Answer (score 155):

You can use the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select elements that contain specific text.
For example:

```
$('#mySelect option:contains(abc)')
```

To check whether a given `<select>` element has such an option, use the [`.has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
if (mySelect.has('option:contains(abc)').length)
```

To find all `<select>`s that contain such an option, use the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('select:has(option:contains(abc))')
```

Comment: `:contains` is not definitive now, is it?

Comment: What is the problem exactly with contains?

Comment: how would you do this with only selected options?

Comment: Doesn't this also grab an option with `123abcdef`?

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, that's the difference between the two top answers. The top only checks returns the option with only the specific text, this one returns the option that contains, but is not only, that specific text. Which, coincidentally, is what I actually need at the moment, so I am very glad posted it.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Less code to deal with but both Floyd and this answer worked. +1 for this

Comment: @Black: No; he's asking for a selector.

Comment: This one should be the top answer as it works with all versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 36):

None of the previous suggestions worked for me in jQuery 1.7.2 because I'm trying to set the selected index of the list based on the value from a textbox, and some text values are contained in multiple options. I ended up using the following:

```
$('#mySelect option:contains(' + value + ')').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == value) {
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it actually returns the correct results. But I can't help but think omitting `contains` altogether may actually speed things up.

Comment: This worked for me but in my scenario I could click edit on a grid multiple times so had to remove the selected attributed when there was no match otherwise the first option selected would remain for subsequent edits.

                else {
                    $(this).attr('selected', '');
                    return false;
                }

Comment: This solution worked for me but instead of setting option attribute, to actually change the select menu I needed to do: `$(this).parent().val($(this).val());`  You could probably do both, but for me setting only the parent `val()` did the trick.

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same issue below is the working code :

```
$("#test option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() =='Ford';
}).prop("selected", true);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/YRBrp/83/

Comment: I'm replacing jquery with cash.js and was stuck trying to replace the jquery :contains selector. This did the trick.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me: `$("#test").find("option:contains('abc')");`

Comment: You should add an explanation of *why* it's working as well.

Comment: @HannesJohansson Or he should at least explain how it's different than or adds something new to SLaks answer that's nearly five years older. ;^)

Comment: Be sure you realize that this will find this option as well: <option>abcd</option>.

Comment: Thanks this is definitly correct and what everyone missed is adding .attr('value'); to the end. This is the easiest way of actually getting the value to use in a dynamic manner! So the full code should like this. 


`$("#testselect").find("option:contains('option-text')").attr('value');`

that way you can use an event like `.click()` to change a setting.

Answer (score 15):

This is the best method for select text in dropdownlist.

```
$("#dropdownid option:contains(your selected text)").attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: As with similar answers, this will find an option with `this is your selected text plus more`.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a few of these things until I got one to work in both Firefox and IE. This is what I came up with.

```
$("#my-Select").val($("#my-Select" + " option").filter(function() { return this.text == myText }).val());
```

another way of writing it in a more readable fasion:

```
var valofText = $("#my-Select" + " option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == myText
}).val();
$(ElementID).val(valofText);
```

Pseudocode:

```
$("#my-Select").val( getValOfText( myText ) );
```

Comment: Makes sense with latest versions of jQuery

Comment: What's the point of `"#my-Select" + " option"`?  Why not just `"#my-Select option"`?

Answer (score 4):

This work for me

```
$('#mySelect option:contains(' + value + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 4):

August 25, 2022.

For jQuery v3.5.1 what really worked for me is this:

```
$('#selectID option:contains("label")').prop('selected', true);
```

If you have the text in a variable, do this:

```
  ddText = 'Text to find';
  $('#selectID option:contains("' + ddText + '")').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following

```
$('#select option:contains(ABC)').val();
```

Comment: the code you provided may resolve the issue but please add a brief description as to how this resolves the issue. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [answer].

Comment: if there some options: ABC, ABCD, ABCDEF, then?

Answer (score 2):

**For jquery version 1.10.2 below worked for me**

```
  var selectedText="YourMatchText";
    $('#YourDropdownId option').map(function () {
       if ($(this).text() == selectedText) return this;
      }).attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var result = $('#SubjectID option')
            .filter(function () 
             { return $(this).html() == "English"; }).val();
```

The `result` variable will return the index of the matched text value. Now I will just set it using it's index:

```
$('#SubjectID').val(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

That was 10 years ago.
Now jquery is EOL, we can use ordinary DOM for this simple job

```
document.getElementById("SomeSelectId").querySelectorAll("option").forEach(o => o.selected = o.innerText == text);
```

Answer (score 2):

This what worked for me on jquery V3.6.0 in 2022

```
$("#select >option").filter( function()
{
    if ($(this).text() === "123")
    {
        $(this).prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

Edit: In 2024, if you want to use a vanilla JS alternative, this is how the code will look like, very simple.

```js
const sel = document.getElementById("cars");
        
// if you need the selected value of the option.
// this will return the numerical ID assigned to the selected car from my example.
// Ex. in case 'Saab' is selected, this will return the string "2".
sel.value;

// if you want the selected car name
const carName = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].innerText;

// if you want the selected option
const selOption = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];

// obviously, you van get the name and value from that option
const name = selOption.innerText;
const id = selOption.value;

// If you want to programmatically select the car "Saab", for example, set 'selectedIndex'
// propriety to the index value of the 'Saab' option in the option's list.
sel.selectedIndex = 1;
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's verbose, but in a good way. Much cleaner and more explicit than the other solutions using the text in the selector itself.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in jQuery 1.6 (note colon before the opening bracket), but fails on the newer releases (1.10 at the time).

```
$('#mySelect option:[text=abc]")
```

Comment: Interesting but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (jQuery 1.10.2).

Comment: You would want to include that something like `$("#mySelect option").filter(function() { return this.text == "abc"; });` will work with latest versions of jQuery.. Or probably some other way which you prefer to use..

Answer (score 1):

use prop instead of attr

```
$('#mySelect option:contains(' + value + ')').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == value) {
        $(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This will also work.

$('#test').find("select option:contains('B')").filter(":selected");

Comment: This will also grab the option `ABC`.

Answer (score -1):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813477/jquery-selector-where-text-some-value/17071290#17071290), you can easily create your own selector for hasText. This allows you to find the option with `$('#test').find('option:hastText("B")').val();`

Here's the hasText method I added:

```
 if( ! $.expr[':']['hasText'] ) {
     $.expr[':']['hasText'] = function( node, index, props ) {
       var retVal = false;
       // Verify single text child node with matching text
       if( node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes.length == 1 ) {
         var childNode = node.childNodes[0];
         retVal = childNode.nodeType == 3 && childNode.nodeValue === props[3];
       }
       return retVal;
     };
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

**This works for me**

```
var options = $(dropdown).find('option');
var targetOption = $(options).filter(
function () { return $(this).html() == value; });

console.log($(targetOption).val());
```

Thanks for all the posts.

Answer (score -3):

Either you iterate through the options, or put the same text inside another attribute of the option and select with that.