# Can CSS select elements with specific content? - answer not posted

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can CSS select elements with specific content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170940/can-css-select-elements-with-specific-content)

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170940/can-css-select-elements-with-specific-content) where @sackbot14 suggested to find the answer.
Unfortunately, the answer was not posted in it.

Any chance to wakeup the bear?

Basically, I would like to locate specific text on a page / within a div, and highlight it or something using HTML and CSS only [no JS, no PHP, no JQuery etc].
Tricks are welcome!

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you put spans on all this specific text or are you saying so it just finds it for you and highlights it?

Comment: You won't be able to do so unless you have commenting privileges, or can find some other way to reach him, I'm afraid...

Comment: what you want is impossible to solve with pure css

Comment: I think the question you linked to is pretty clear about it - this is not possible with only CSS.