# Javascript - Get atribute from select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello there dear community.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="Pcolor" id="image" style="height:30px;">
    <option value="">Избран цвят: Blue/Lt Blue </option>
    <option value="45751303" color-number="0">Black</option>
    <option value="45751343" color-number="1">Black/Pink</option>
    <option value="45751359" color-number="2">Blue/Lt Blue</option>
    <option value="45751324" color-number="3">Dk Purple/Purpl</option>
    <option value="45751390" color-number="4">Ink/Cerise</option>
</select>
```

I want to ask how i can get the `color-number` attribute number where option text is `Blue/Lt Blue` for example ?

**It is important to make it only with JavaScript/jQuery !**

I hope you understand what i want to describe, thanks in advance!

Comment: Iron man, What did you tried? I am sure you want to share code with us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery : How to select an option by its text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744289/jquery-how-to-select-an-option-by-its-text)

Comment: See `.attr()` or `.prop()` jQuery functions. Also a suggestion, Use `data-colorNumber` instead of `color-number`

Comment: [This tells you how to do this exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3744305/542251) closing as duplicate. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oreyuvmx/)

Answer (score 2):

I would do this way:

```
$('#image option[value="Blue/Lt Blue"]').attr("color-number");
```

So essentially you search for the correct option and get it attribute.

Comment: `$('#image option[value=45751359]').attr("color-number");`

Comment: I think the option `value` is not `Blue/Lt Blue` like you point in your answer. It must find the option for the text in it `<option>TEXT HERE</option>`

Answer (score 2):

Using [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) won't be a proper solution as it will return partial matches, instead you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```js
var text = 'Black/Pink';
var cn = $('select[name="Pcolor"] option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == text;
}).attr('color-number');

console.log(cn)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Pcolor" id="image" style="height:30px;">
  <option value="">Избран цвят: Blue/Lt Blue</option>
  <option value="45751303" color-number="0">Black</option>
  <option value="45751343" color-number="1">Black/Pink</option>
  <option value="45751359" color-number="2">Blue/Lt Blue</option>
  <option value="45751324" color-number="3">Dk Purple/Purpl</option>
  <option value="45751390" color-number="4">Ink/Cerise</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#image').on('change',function() {
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('color-number'));
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cw6knsc5/2/