# How can I hide some options from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display only Australia's cities in dropdown list. How can I able to do it? I trying to find "Australia" in option and hide before it and after it. but failed!

**[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uo31jjjn/)**.

```
<select class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option disabled="">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SIN">Singapore</option>
    <option disabled="">Australia</option>
    <option value="ADL">Adelaide</option>
    <option value="AYQ">Ayers Rock / Uluru</option>
    <option value="BNE">Brisbane</option>
    <option value="CNS">Cairns</option>
    <option value="CBR">Canberra</option>
    <option value="OOL">Gold Coast</option>
    <option value="HBA">Hobart</option>
    <option value="LST">Launceston</option>
    <option value="MEL">Melbourne</option>
    <option value="PER">Perth</option>
    <option value="MCY">Sunshine Coast</option>
    <option value="SYD">Sydney</option>
    <option disabled="">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="DAC">Dhaka</option>
    <option disabled="">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BWN">Bandar Seri Begawan</option>
    <option disabled="">China</option>
    <option value="CKG">Chongqing</option>
    <option value="DLC">Dalian</option>
    <option value="CAN">Guangzhou</option>
    <option value="HAK">Haikou</option>
    <option value="HGH">Hangzhou</option>
    <option value="HRB">Harbin</option>
    <option value="TNA">Jinan</option>
    <option value="NKG">Nanjing</option>
    <option value="NNG">Nanning</option>
    <option value="NGB">Ningbo</option>
    <option value="TAO">Qingdao</option>
    <option value="JJN">Quanzhou</option>
    <option value="SHE">Shenyang</option>
    <option value="SZX">Shenzhen</option>
    <option value="TSN">Tianjin</option>
    <option value="WUX">Wuxi/Suzhou</option>
    <option value="XIY">Xi'an</option>
    <option value="CGO">Zhengzhou</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried? please show us

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744323/2181514

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of the options you want to keep you could loop over the options and hide them if they don't have this value:

```
var select = $("#dropdown");

for (var i = 0; i < select .length; i++){
   if (select.options[i].value != 'YOURVALUE' )
       select.css("display":"none");
}
```

Replace **YOURVALUE** with the values of the options you want to keep i.e. the value that cities in Australia have.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the value in dropdown list, use

```
<option value="TNA" style="display:none;">Jinan</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/9ga7tdnv/1/)**.

Since you're using jQuery you could use `nextUntil()` to select all the options from `Australia` until the next country like :

```
//Hide all
$('#dropdown option').hide(); 

//Get the target
var australia = $('#dropdown').find('option:contains("Australia")');

//Select the targeted country & Show all the cities until the next country
australia.attr('selected','selected').show().nextUntil("option[disabled]" ).show();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#dropdown option').hide(); 
var australia = $('#dropdown').find('option:contains("Australia")');
australia.attr('selected','selected').show().nextUntil( "option[disabled]" ).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option disabled="">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SIN">Singapore</option>
    <option disabled="">Australia</option>
    <option value="ADL">Adelaide</option>
    <option value="AYQ">Ayers Rock / Uluru</option>
    <option value="BNE">Brisbane</option>
    <option value="CNS">Cairns</option>
    <option value="CBR">Canberra</option>
    <option value="OOL">Gold Coast</option>
    <option value="HBA">Hobart</option>
    <option value="LST">Launceston</option>
    <option value="MEL">Melbourne</option>
    <option value="PER">Perth</option>
    <option value="MCY">Sunshine Coast</option>
    <option value="SYD">Sydney</option>
    <option disabled="">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="DAC">Dhaka</option>
    <option disabled="">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BWN">Bandar Seri Begawan</option>
    <option disabled="">China</option>
    <option value="CKG">Chongqing</option>
    <option value="DLC">Dalian</option>
    <option value="CAN">Guangzhou</option>
    <option value="HAK">Haikou</option>
    <option value="HGH">Hangzhou</option>
    <option value="HRB">Harbin</option>
    <option value="TNA">Jinan</option>
    <option value="NKG">Nanjing</option>
    <option value="NNG">Nanning</option>
    <option value="NGB">Ningbo</option>
    <option value="TAO">Qingdao</option>
    <option value="JJN">Quanzhou</option>
    <option value="SHE">Shenyang</option>
    <option value="SZX">Shenzhen</option>
    <option value="TSN">Tianjin</option>
    <option value="WUX">Wuxi/Suzhou</option>
    <option value="XIY">Xi'an</option>
    <option value="CGO">Zhengzhou</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, what i really want to show in dorpdown is those values; not only 'Australia'. sorry about confusion.
Australia, Adelaide, Ayers Rock / Uluru ... Sydney.

Answer (score 0):

> display only Australia's cities

Assuming your list contains the country (disabled option) followed *directly* by its cities followed by another disabled option:

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744323/2181514) to find the Australia `option`:

```
var aus = $('option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Australia"; });
```

then use `.nextAll` to find the next disabled `option` and get the `option` before that using `prev()` and `.index()` on both of them.

then hide entries that don't match that index range

finally, tidy up by selecting the first `option`

```
aus.attr('selected', true);
```

```js
var aus = $('option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Australia"; });
var ifrom = aus.index();
var ito = aus.nextAll("[disabled]").first().prev().index();

$("option").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).index() < ifrom || $(this).index() > ito 
}).hide();

aus.attr('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="popup_origin_select" class="origin-select-shared" id="popup_origin_select_return">
    <option disabled="">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SIN">Singapore</option>
    <option disabled="">Australia</option>
    <option value="ADL">Adelaide</option>
    <option value="AYQ">Ayers Rock / Uluru</option>
    <option value="BNE">Brisbane</option>
    <option value="CNS">Cairns</option>
    <option value="CBR">Canberra</option>
    <option value="OOL">Gold Coast</option>
    <option value="HBA">Hobart</option>
    <option value="LST">Launceston</option>
    <option value="MEL">Melbourne</option>
    <option value="PER">Perth</option>
    <option value="MCY">Sunshine Coast</option>
    <option value="SYD">Sydney</option>
    <option disabled="">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="DAC">Dhaka</option>
    <option disabled="">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BWN">Bandar Seri Begawan</option>
    <option disabled="">China</option>
    <option value="CKG">Chongqing</option>
    <option value="DLC">Dalian</option>
    <option value="CAN">Guangzhou</option>
    <option value="HAK">Haikou</option>
    <option value="HGH">Hangzhou</option>
    <option value="HRB">Harbin</option>
    <option value="TNA">Jinan</option>
    <option value="NKG">Nanjing</option>
    <option value="NNG">Nanning</option>
    <option value="NGB">Ningbo</option>
    <option value="TAO">Qingdao</option>
    <option value="JJN">Quanzhou</option>
    <option value="SHE">Shenyang</option>
    <option value="SZX">Shenzhen</option>
    <option value="TSN">Tianjin</option>
    <option value="WUX">Wuxi/Suzhou</option>
    <option value="XIY">Xi'an</option>
    <option value="CGO">Zhengzhou</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, This help a lot, but, for 'China', i got error. Nothing shown.

Comment: China is the last country entry, so you'll need to handle that by checking if `nextAll("[disabled]")` returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var australiaCities=[] // Array of Australia cities 
    $("#dropdown option").each(function(){
        if(australiaCities.indexOf($(this).val())==-1){
            $(this).hide();
        }// check if this option value is not in autraliaCities so hide this option 
    )};
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd put all of the cities into an object, keyed by country - you'll find it much easier to manipulate an object than having all your data stored as HTML elements. For instance, here you just pass the country name to a function and it pulls the data out of the stored object and inserts to your :

```
var countries = {};
var curr;

function showCities(selectedCountry) {
    var h = '<option disabled>' + selectedCountry + '</option>';
  $.each(countries[selectedCountry], function(i, c) {
    h += '<option value="' + c.value + '">' + c.name + '</option>';
  });
  $('#popup_origin_select_return').html(h);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup_origin_select_return option').each(function(i) {
    if($(this)[0].hasAttribute("disabled")) {
        countries[$(this).text()] = [];
      curr = $(this).text();
    } else {
        countries[curr].push({
        value: $(this).val(),
        name: $(this).text()
      });
    }
  });
    showCities('China');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo31jjjn/5/

Comment: Thanks, but this will remove <option disabled="">China</option> as well.

Comment: Well, the original question said to display just the cities, no mention of the country, but that's very easy as well, just need to replace the var h declaration with `var h = '<option disabled>' + selectedCountry + '</option>';` and this should then include the country at the top of the list. I have updated the code in my answer, take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5's custom data-* attribute. That is you add to all options 
`data-country="some country"` and iterate through that with for example jQuery:

```
var isolated = "australia";
$("option").each(function(){
    var opt = $(this);
    if(opt.attr("data-country")!==isolated){
        opt.hide();
    }
});
```

(I hope the syntax is somewhat OK)

[data-* attribute documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

EDIT:
Another solution comes to mind is to use [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup).
Your select would look like this:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <optgroup label="Australia">
        <option value="ADL">Adelaide</option>
        <option value="AYQ">Ayers Rock / Uluru</option>
        <option value="BNE">Brisbane</option>
        <option value="CNS">Cairns</option>
        <option value="CBR">Canberra</option>
        <option value="OOL">Gold Coast</option>
        <option value="HBA">Hobart</option>
        <option value="LST">Launceston</option>
        <option value="MEL">Melbourne</option>
        <option value="PER">Perth</option>
        <option value="MCY">Sunshine Coast</option>
        <option value="SYD">Sydney</option>
    </optgroup>
    .
    .
    .
</select>
```

But that's not much of a difference and you can't use `hidden` on it, only `disabled`.