# Definitive indexOf instead of option:contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

Is there a jQuery selector to replace **:contains** with a more definitive **indexOf**, for example? I am trying to match for variable VALUE_XYZ

The problem is that the code finds strings that are similar (because it contains the string) before it gets to the value that is exact.

```
var value= $("select[name=BU_CT_NUM_DOC]").find('option:contains($VALUE_XYZ)').val();
```

The entire code looks like this and is encapsulated by xslt:

```
<xsl:when test="/Root/Form/EDIT_BU_TYPE = 'd' or /Root/Form/EDIT_BU_NOTIFICATION_TYPE='d'"><![CDATA[
 var value = $("select[name=BU_CT_NUM_DOC]").find('option:contains($VALUE_XYZ)').val();
 $("#BU_CT_NUM_DOC").val(value).attr('selected',true).trigger("chosen:updated");
]]></xsl:when>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an index of selector, but using the filter technique from [How to select an option by its text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744289/how-to-select-an-option-by-its-text) you can match the entire text of the string, or you could modify the filter function to use indexOf.

```js
var $VALUE_XYZ = "AB";
var value = $("select[name=BU_CT_NUM_DOC]").find('option').filter( function() { return $(this).html() == $VALUE_XYZ } ).first().val();
console.log( value );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="BU_CT_NUM_DOC">
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
<option value="ab">AB</option>
</select>
```