# How to set select2 selected value using option text?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 with a delivery date calendar, available dates are listed like this.

```
<select name="e_deliverydate" id="e_deliverydate" class="select select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Escolha uma data" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="select">Select a delivery date</option>
   <option value="18-9-2021">sábado, 18 setembro, 2021</option>
   <option value="21-9-2021">terça-feira, 21 setembro, 2021</option>
   <option value="22-9-2021">quarta-feira, 22 setembro, 2021</option>
   <option value="23-9-2021">quinta-feira, 23 setembro, 2021</option>
   <option value="24-9-2021">sexta-feira, 24 setembro, 2021</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to set the selected option using the option text?
I'm trying this:

```
let date_string = 'quarta-feira, 22 Setembro, 2021';

let val = $('#e_deliverydate').find("option:contains('"+date_string+"')").val();

$('#e_deliverydate').val(val).trigger('change.select2');
```

But all I get to do is to empty the select2 input, I'm using select2 4.0x, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744323/13604954

Comment: it does not work for select2.js though :(

Comment: maybe replace `option:contains('"+date_string+"')` by `option:contains['"+date_string+"']`

Comment: it just returns a syntax error, isn't [] for arrays only?

Comment: Based on this link :https://select2.org/searching you need to customize a function.

Comment: this is not what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your Date string

```
let date_string = 'quarta-feira, 22 Setembro, 2021';
```

Can you try it for val

```
let val = $("#e_deliverydate option").filter(function() { 

    return $(this).text().includes(date_string) 

}).val();
```

And this for trigger

```
$('#e_deliverydate').val(val).trigger('change');
```