# Select option from a select with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

In a `select`, how I can select a particular `option` ?

For example, I want to select the option with 3 from this select ?

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option disabled>10x10</option>
    <option disabled>20x20</option>
    <option disabled>30x30</option>
</select>
```

What I have tried:

```
$('select[name="dropdown"] option[text="20x20"]').attr('disabled', false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note there is an answer for plain DOM (no jQuery) as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69042215/215552

Comment: That said, your attempt `$('select[name="dropdown"] option[text="20x20"]')` doesn't really match your question body ("I want to select the option with 3 from this select")