# jquery find span with special text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select a span with specific text in jquery. Jquery "contains" is not very strict, so if I use it and search for "tab", it would also select "table", which I dont want.

```
$(".spanbox:contains('Tab')").css('background-color', 'Green')
```

The example-spans:

```
<span class="spanbox">Tab</span>
<span class="spanbox">Table</span>
```

Is there a way to exclusively select on of the classes members with a certain text?

Comment: Flagged as duplicate. OP, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/813688/614152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a function parameter, like so:

```
$(".spanbox").filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() == 'Tab';
}).css('background-color', 'Green');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
$.fn.textEquals = function (text) {
    var match = false;
    $(this).each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().match("^" + escapeRegex(text) + "$")) {
            match = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return match;
};

$(".spanbox").textEquals('Tab').css('background-color', 'Green');
$(".spanbox").textEquals('Table').css('background-color', 'Red');
```