# how to get option index based on option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have try to find option index bases on option text. My HTML code is bellow.

```
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="dependentOptions.select(this); opConfig.reloadPrice();optionImages.showImage(this);" title="" class="multiselect product-custom-option" id="select_472" name="options[472][]" >
<option selected="selected" value="3364">Black </option>
<option selected="selected" value="3365">White </option>
<option value="3366">Cool Grey #9 </option>
<option value="3367">Red </option>
<option value="3368">Fire Red </option>
<option value="3369">Orange </option>
<option value="3370">Rich Yellow </option>
<option value="3371">Primrose Yellow </option>
<option value="3372">Light Green </option>
</select>
```

and my script is like this

```
jQuery("#select_472 select option:[text=Rich Yellow]").index();
```

but it return me -1 insted of 7

So please help me to sove this.

Comment: Second `select` is wrong in jQuery selection, you should remove it.

Comment: Some other options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813477/jquery-selector-where-text-some-value

Comment: Be aware, index is zero based, so here it will be 6 not 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
jQuery("#select_472 option:contains('Rich Yellow')").index();
```

Comment: Could be some issue with `:contains`, e.g between Fire Red and Red

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, it's a good point! Filter is a better choice here.

Answer (score 2):

The index should be began on 0 so the text 'Rich Yellow' be index position is 6.

```
$("#select_472 option[value='3370']").index();

$("#select_472 option:contains('Rich Yellow ')").index();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ddcx81n0/1/)

Comment: `based on option text`. You're going off the value and not the text.

Comment: The one involving the "value = ..." is exactly what I have been looking for.  All other answers on SO, some of them very clever, that I have found to achieve this task appear to use brute force looping through the options.  But your way of getting the index from the value (apparently) doesn't.  I therefore plussed you despite this not answering the OP's specific question!

Answer (score 1):

You could filter it (and trim text value), looks more safe:

```
jQuery("#select_472 option").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Rich Yellow"
}).index();
```